# mod_perl can't see files in /tmp

Tags: linux, apache, perl, mod-perl, rhel7

I have some mod_perl code trying to access a file under /tmp ... but it throws a 'no such file or directory' error.  I added an 'ls -al /tmp' to my code to see what Perl was seeing inside the directory, and it only gave me . and .. :

```
drwxrwxrwt.  2 root root        6 Jan 21 13:36 .
drwxrwxrwx. 18 root sysadmin 4096 Nov 22 22:14 ..
```

In reality there are a mixture of files under /tmp, including some owned by the Apache user. Changing my code to 'ls -al /' gives a correct directory listing (nothing missing).

I tried sudo'ing to the Apache user, and can see under /tmp file, so it must be something mod_perl related.

Ideas? I'm running mod_perl 2.0.8 and Apache 2.4 under CentOS 7. SELinux is set to permissive.

Comment: I can't answer precisely, but I would be wondering if some sort of chrooting is going on. E.g. `/tmp` as far as mod_perl is concerned isn't the same as the real `/tmp`. I'd suggest creating a file in `/tmp` from mod_perl and see if that appears as you expect.

Comment: Bingo, it's a feature called PrivateTmp, new to RHEL 7:

https://securityblog.redhat.com/2014/04/09/new-red-hat-enterprise-linux-7-security-feature-privatetmp/

Answer (score 3):

So based on comments the answer here is - it's an RHEL 7 feature. 
https://securityblog.redhat.com/2014/04/09/new-red-hat-enterprise-linux-7-security-feature-privatetmp/

> PrivateTmp=
>
> Takes a boolean argument. If true sets up a new file system
>      namespace for the executed processes and mounts a private /tmp
>      directory inside it, that is not shared by processes outside of
>      the namespace. This is useful to secure access to temporary files
>      of the process, but makes sharing between processes via /tmp
>      impossible. Defaults to false.

Comment: This is the answer I'm looking for for two days. Thank you :)