# Twig 1.x - Configuring cache to /tmp don't work

Tags: php, linux, caching, twig, silex

If I configure Twig's cache to `myapp/storage/cache` and manually set the correct permissions it works, but configuring it to `sys_get_temp_dir()` (which returns `/tmp`) doesn't seem to work. File structure in `/tmp` remains the same, altough no error is triggered.

My block of code is like this:

```
// [...]
$app->register(new \Silex\Provider\TwigServiceProvider(), array(
    'twig.path' => __DIR__ . '/templates',
    'twig.options' => array(
        'cache' => sys_get_temp_dir(), // If changed to myapp/storage/cache, it works.
    ),
));
```

Comment: I would like to avoid the need to set proper permissions to cache folder manually because I'm doing a boilerplate. Less manual configuration would be better.

Comment: Why do you want to place the files inside `/tmp`?

Comment: have you tried to manually create a file inside this directory?

Comment: @DarkBee mainly because it's a boilerplate and making user change folder permissions is not good nor comfortable. /tmp is already there with the right permissions.

Comment: @mTorres yes. Creating a file there worked, but Twig didn't do anything even manually creating the folders.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28082846/mod-perl-cant-see-files-in-tmp) is why I was not able to see the temp files.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this can help you, but it is possible to override the default `writeCacheFile` method of the `Twig_Environment`. By doing so you can create the temporary folder yourself and apply the wanted permissions, so your user don't have to do this themself.

<kbd>Custom Twig_Env</kbd>

```
class Environment extends \Twig_Environment {
    protected function writeCacheFile($file, $content){
        createDirectoryTree(dirname($file));
        parent::writeCacheFile($file, $content);
        chmod($file,0664);
        chgrp($file, 'psacln');
        chown($file, 'www-data');
    }
}
```

<kbd>Functions.php</kbd>

```
function createDirectoryTree($folder) {
    if (is_dir($folder)) return;
    $folder = str_replace('/', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $folder);
    $branches = explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $folder);
    $tree = '';

    $old_mask = umask(0);
    while(!empty($branches)) {
        $tree .= array_shift($branches).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
        if (!@file_exists($tree)) {

            if (@mkdir($tree, 0774)){
                chown($tree, 'www-data');
                chgrp($tree, 'psacln');
            }
        }
    }
    umask($old_mask);
}
```

Comment: Thank you @DarkBee. The "problem" is because a security feature implemented in RHEL7. Files were being creating normally, however in a private context that could not be seen for external processes. That's why I assumed that they were not being created: I was using terminal and / or file manager to check if the cache existed. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28082846/mod-perl-cant-see-files-in-tmp) for more information.

Comment: Good thing you got it sorted out in the end